# AngularJS Duplicate Filter in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter the duplicates in the following nested ng-repeat directives :

```
<li ng-repeat="info in firstObject">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="moreInfo in info.Details" >{{moreInfo.location}}</li>
  </ul> 
</li>
```

So, every info object has more moreInfo which can be the same. Can you help me filter them? Thanks.

Comment: You could try `info in firstObject track by info.moreInfo` [(ngRepeat - tracking & duplicates)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) or create a custom filter - depends on what feels best for you